# Play music from laptop through XBMC on TV?

Tags: kodi, file-sharing

Is it possible to play music (or even video) stored on my laptop HDD, through XBMC which is running on my Pi attached to the TV?

Comment: From what are you controlling all this from?

Comment: Can you control the machine from ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you install a DLNA server on your Laptop, or share the music folder on the laptop, XBMC can read from the share to play music on your TV.

If the laptop is running Linux, then a NFS share is the way to do it.
Otherwise if it's running Windows, XBMC can read SMB shares as well.

Installing a DLNA server will be the least mucking around with fileshares and possible permissions issues, but it's also a bit more configuration and setting up in the beginning.

With all of these methods, all of the controlling will be done from XBMC. The laptop will simply be used as a datastore for the media.

Answer (score 0):

Film and Music in iTunes require airplay to be activated in XMBC.